# Inheriting type parameter classes in Scala

Tags: scala

I have one abstract class with type parameter and few its implementations:

```
abstract class AbstractClass[T] {
    def func: T
}

class DoubleClass extends AbstractClass[Double]{
    def func = 0.0
}
```

and then I want to create a function that takes some sequence of such objects:

```
def someFunc(objs: Iterable[AbstractClass]) = objs.foreach(obj=>println(obj.func))
```

but it says "Class AbstractClass takes type parameters"

I am new at scala and definitely doing something wrong, but i can`t figure out what

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should in most cases be `def someFunc[A](objs: Iterable[AbstractClass[A]])`. In particular, this allows return type to depend on `A`, e.g.

```
def someFunc[A](objs: Iterable[AbstractClass[A]]) = objs.map(_.func)
```

returns `Iterable[A]`.

Sometimes you may actually want to allow mixing `AbstractClass`es with different parameters. E.g. in your example you just print `func`, which can always be done. In this case, as Sascha Kolberg's answer says, use a wildcard:

```
def someFunc(objs: Iterable[AbstractClass[_]])
```

But if you find yourself using wildcards constantly, consider rethinking your design.

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution would be to add the wildcard type as type argument to `AbstractClass` in your function:

```
def someFunc(objs: Iterable[AbstractClass[_]]) = objs.foreach(obj=>println(obj.func))
```

This way `objs` can be an iterable containing any kind of `AbstractClass`, so essentially a mixed type collection.

If you want to be sure, that the iterable argument of `someFunc` holds only instances of one implementation of AbstractClass[_], you can add another type parameter to someFunc:

```
def someFunc[A <: AbstractClass[_]](objs: Iterable[A]) = objs.foreach(obj=>println(obj.func))
```

`<:` is a type bound that basically says that `A` is a subclass of `AbstractClass[_]`